# Integrating functions with respect to different variables

Tags: calculus

When going through calculus and physics, I'm finding many integrals that seem to be integrating functions with respect to variables that aren't the dummy variable of the function. One example is the integral for the surface area of a solid of revolution being written as $2\pi\int_{a}^{b} f(x) ds$ instead of $2\pi\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)\sqrt{1+\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)^{2}}dx$ or $2\pi\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{2}}dx$. The textbook I'm working out of for calculus says you can just "substitute" $ds=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{2}}dx$ whenever you have $ds$ within the integral. My physics book says a similar thing about the integrals for moment of inertia and center of mass. My question is, can you treat differentials like $ds$ and $dx$ like variables when integrating and "substitute" values? I thought that the $dx$ within the integral came from the infinitely small width of an interval in a Darboux or a Reimann sum, meaning it's in some sense tied to the independent variable of the function you're integrating.

I'm aware you often change the integration variable when solving integrals using u-substitution, but as far as I know this is just a notational shortcut for using the chain rule. Is a similar thing at play here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the $ds$ in this case is functioning as shorthand for $\sqrt {1 +f'(x)} \ dx$, but most calculus books will clarify what "ds" means rather than telling you to "just substitute it in,", i.e. $$2\pi \int_a^{b} f(x) \ ds \text {, where } ds = \sqrt {1 +f'(x)} \ dx.$$